# flutterfire crashlytics not enable

Tags: firebase, flutter, crashlytics

not enable crashlyrics in firebase console, after

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();
```

my code

```
Future<void> main() async {
  //runZonedGuarded<Future<void>>(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
    FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();//this i also set in initState and build
    runApp(const MyApp());
  //}, (error, stack) => FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack));
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
```

android/build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'    
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
```

Tried start app with `flutter run --release`

also I tried use this example with my `options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform`:  https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics/example/lib/main.dart

I did everything according to the instructions from here https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/  Getting started and Craslytics

don't have any errors, except for crashlytics not working in the firebase console

Comment: can you share some code  so, can get idea

Comment: @HardikMehta edit

Comment: Can you add this line FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();  on initstate method  of other screen instaed of main method ?

Comment: @HardikMehta I already added to initState and Widget build, I also tried it in the button, I used runZonedGuarded for this, it didn’t bring any result, it seems to me that I did something wrong with build.gradle, but all I added there was I found from the stackoverflow and issues with github

Comment: Are you not able to get crash report or  not able to crash  the app  ? if not getting report then you have to run the app again [remove crash statement ] after force crash  then you will able to see crash in console.

Comment: @HardikMehta I can't get the first crash report, I did the restart both in debug mode, run, and run --release, I commented on the line with the forced crash and left it before the second launch, I did the second flutter project, where just a counter and code that I didn't touch, almost 24 hours have passed with the working project, and with the second project a little more than 12 hours (I saw that it can be processed within 24 hours, but the instructions say about 5 minutes)

Comment: first do crash then run the app again without any crash statement and you will see crash  report in firebase console

Comment: @HardikMehta I've done it already, now I've even made a second screen in which I made forced crash, I run it a second time, there's nothing in the console, is there any way to track whether it sends a report at all or not?

Comment: Second time you have to run without crash statement

Comment: @HardikMehta I've already done a bunch of options, the problem turned out to be in android 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by another device, with android 11, with it there was a log about the request for crashlytics
There was no request on my device with 12 android, so far I will put the issue resolved, although I would like to have a solution to the problem for 12 android

Comment: Are you using latest firebase_crashlytics latest sdk ?

Comment: @HardikMehta firebase_crashlytics: ^2.5.0 firebase_core: ^1.12.0

Comment: Any solution for Android 12. Still i am not getting crash report in firebase dashboard